# prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda x_{n} = \lambda \cdot L $ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \neq 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

I asked this question since I have already proven the easy case for when $ \lambda = 0$

prove that $ lim_{n \to \infty}  \lambda x_{n} = \lambda \cdot L $ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ where $L$ is limit of $x_n$

I'm just wondering how I would approach it using the definition of a limit. If someone could just nudge me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\varepsilon>0$ and define $\varepsilon' = \frac{\varepsilon}{|\lambda|}$. Then you know there exists $N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ $$|x_n-L|<\varepsilon'$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: We then get $ |\lambda x_n - \lambda L| < {\epsilon}' $ should both $L$ and $x_n$ be multiplied with $\lambda$ ? Not just $L$ ? Can you explain to me why this is the case? Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: No problem. Also, you want to drop the $'$ off of $\varepsilon'$ since you multiplied across by $|\lambda|$. So you started with an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and you know there is that necessary $N$ condition being satisfied. You also know $|\lambda x_n-\lambda L|<\varepsilon$. Are there any more requirements to conclude that $\lambda x_n \to \lambda L$? If you aren't sure, try setting $\lambda x_n = a_n$ and $\lambda L = A$ to see if everything looks okay.

Comment: Oh I see it clearly, don't know how I missed it. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: No problem JohnDoe! Happy to help. A lot of these limit proofs become simpler when you define a special $\varepsilon'$ in terms of $\varepsilon.$ I encourage you to next try proving (if you haven't yet) that $$x_n \to L \neq 0 \implies \frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{L}$$. It's a fun one ;)

Comment: I'll give it a go !

Comment: $ {\epsilon}' = \frac{1}{Lx_n} $ ?

Comment: You can't have a member of the sequence $x_n$ in the definition of $\varepsilon'$, because that could mean $\varepsilon'$ is not a constant. Plus $x_n$ or $L$ could be negative.

Answer (score 2):

For $\lambda > 0$:

1. Write down definition of $x_n\to L$.
2. Think where to put $\lambda$ there.

Think how (whether?) the case $\lambda<0$ is different.